# Pygame objects on the screen moved after windows update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I made this projectile motion project not too long ago, and it was in pygame. The finished product was done via pyinstaller so it was an exe, and other computers could run it without python. I even made an NSIS installer for it. But after i did a windows update, (from v1709), the text on the screen is different, some parts are larger than they were before, some smaller, some are shifted right a bit? Is there any possible explanation for this? EDIT: Added photos, some reason 1 is larger than the other, but the top one is "BEFORE" and the second one is "AFTER". Nothing was changed, this was comparison of 1 laptop after using the installer to install it, vs the installer being run on my computer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the font size increased. Did you set the font size in the application?  Are the fonts scaled in your system (ie 125%) ?

Comment: I concur with Mike67.  When the font is rendered, you can get the width & height on the resultant Surface, and use this for relative positioning.  It's a lot of mucking around, but it would allow you to properly align columns etc.

Comment: sorry for late reply, uhm, no the scaling on windows is set to 100%, if its something different im not sure how to change font scaling of the system? Thanks

Comment: actually, just found it. No, the font scaling is set to 100%.

Comment: @Kingsley yes, probably would be something in the future to do for the program, but my problem is it is an executable, ableto run on different devices, and unable to change the actual exe file itself (or atleast i havent), yet this still happened.